# SubString extraction from a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have this variable called var, whose value is as shown below.

```
$ echo $var   
{'active_production_dc':'sc-tx2','standby_production_dc':'sc_tx3','active_integration_dc':'int_tx3','standby_integration-dc':'int_va1'}
```

From this output , I need to extract the values of

```
'active_production_dc', 
'standby_production_dc', 
'active_integration_dc' and 
'standby_integration_dc' into four different variables.
```

The below one just extracting keys. I want to extract the keys into variables.

```
printf "%s" "$var" | awk 'NR>1 && NR%2' RS="({'|'.'|'})"
```

if I

```
echo $active_production_dc
```

then it should return

```
sc-tx2
```

Something like that.
Basically the value for active_production_dc should be saved inside the variable.

Comment: please post the regular expressions you tried and failed, along with output/errors

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560381/substring-extraction-from-a-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for original question

Let's start with your variable:

```
$ echo "$var"
{'active-production-dc':'sc-tx2','standby-production-dc':'sc-tx3','active-integration-dc':'int-tx3','standby-integration-dc':'int-va1'}
```

#### Using jq

`jq` does not accept the string as is.  We must first replace the single-quotes with double-quotes.  Then we can extract the keys:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/'\''/"/g' | jq keys
[
  "active-integration-dc",
  "active-production-dc",
  "standby-integration-dc",
  "standby-production-dc"
]
```

#### Using awk

Using awk to extract the keys:

```
$ printf "%s" "$var" | awk 'NR%2==0' RS="({'|'.'|'})"
active-production-dc
standby-production-dc
active-integration-dc
standby-integration-dc
```

Using awk to extract the values that correspond to those keys:

```
$ printf "%s" "$var" | awk 'NR>1 && NR%2' RS="({'|'.'|'})"
sc-tx2
sc-tx3
int-tx3
int-va1
```

### Answer for revised question

For the revised question, we need a new `var`:

```
$ echo "$var"
{'active_production_dc':'sc-tx2','standby_production_dc':'sc_tx3','active_integration_dc':'int_tx3','standby_integration_dc':'int_va1'}
```

We can create shell variables named after the keys like this:

```
$ while IFS=":" read -r -d, key val; do declare "$key=$val"; done < <(echo "$var" | sed "s/[{}']//g; s/$/,/")
```

When this is done the keys and values are accessible:

```
$ echo "$active_production_dc"
sc-tx2
```

Alternatively, and probably preferably, we can make the keys and values available in bash via an associative array.  Use:

```
declare -A a
while IFS=":" read -r -d, key val
do
    a["$key"]="$val"
done < <(echo "$var" | sed "s/[{}']//g; s/$/,/")
```

When this is run, using the value for `var` in the revised question, then the resulting `a` contains the keys and values:

```
$ declare -p a
declare -A a='([standby_integration_dc]="int_va1" [active_production_dc]="sc-tx2" [active_integration_dc]="int_tx3" [standby_production_dc]="sc_tx3" )'
```

An individual value can be accessed via its key:

```
$ echo "${a[active_production_dc]}"
sc-tx2
```

Comment: The `sed` is useful as a demonstration, but to be safe, you (the OP) should fix whatever is producing the value of `var` in the first place. `sed` can't distinguish between single quotes that are used to quote the keys and values, and single quotes that might be embedded *in* the value.

Comment: I am unable to execute . It is saying broken pipe error. Can you put complete code

Comment: @user3479901 I just copy-and-pasted the code from my answer to my shell and it works for me.  If you continue to get a broken pipe error, please tell me which command it happens on and let me see the _complete_ error message.

Comment: I  edited the question. Could you please re-check it?

Comment: @user3479901 I have added those features to the revised answer.

Comment: I am Glad that it is working. But one small problem. 
At the final variable it is printing blank. First three variables are printing fine. 
If I add    ,      (to the var at the end) it will print the final variable. How can I fix this !

Comment: @user3479901 OK.  I think I just fixed the problem with the last variable.   Also, as you probably know, it has to be renamed `standby-integration-dc` --> `standby-integration_dc`

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P` you can do:

```
arr=($(grep -Po '(?<=[{,])[a-zA-Z0-9-]+' <<< "$s"))

# print resulting array
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
active-production-dc
standby-production-dc
active-integration-dc
standby-integration-dc
```

However your input appears to be a JSON and you should consider using `jq` to parse it reliably.

Comment: I need like this. I am able to extract using AWK .

    printf "%s" "$var" | awk 'NR>1 && NR%2' RS="({'|'.'|'})"



Or if I echo $active-production-dc, then it should return sc-tx2
Something like that.

 Basically the value for "active-production-dc" should be saved inside the variable.

Comment: You cannot have a variable name `active-production-dc` in Unix as hyphen is not allowed in variable names

Comment: Yes. Its  a point. Shall we extract 'active-production-dc', 'standby-production-dc', 'active-integration-dc' and 'standby-integration-dc' values into four different variables?

Comment: It is better to work with arrays. If you have BASH 4+ then you can use associative arrays as well

Answer (score 0):

A second on using `jq` to parse the JSON, but if you are required to parse it in bash, then a second option is an array, controlling the `IFS` (internal field separator) and *parameter expansion* with *substring removal*. Use `jq` in practice:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="{'active-production-dc':'sc-tx2','standby-production-dc':'sc-tx3',\
'active-integration-dc':'int-tx3','standby-integration-dc':'int-va1'}"

IFS=$','
a=( $(echo "$var") )

for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i++)); do 
    b=${a[i]}
    b=${b#*\{}
    b=${b%\}*}
    a[i]="${b%:*}"
done

printf "%s\n" ${a[@]}
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parsevar.sh
'active-production-dc'
'standby-production-dc'
'active-integration-dc'
'standby-integration-dc'
```